# Change date using Jquery inside a function

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker, string-formatting

I'm using jquery.datepicker and I need to display the date selected in a more readable format. Here is the code that I'm using:

```
    $(function(){
                $('#dp').datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'yymmdd',
                    numberOfMonths: 3,
                    minDate: 0,
                    maxDate: 60
                });
                $('#date').on('click', function() {
                    $('#dp').datepicker('show');            
                });
                $("#dp").change(function() {
//#NEW DATE FORMAT = EDIT FORMAT OF #DP
                    $("#showDate").html($("#NEW DATE FORMAT").val());
                    $(".eventDate").addClass('eventAdded dateProvided');
                });
});
```

So I need to convert the value of #DP but only for display purposes in the #showDate.html element. I hope that makes sense

Comment: What should it show? What have you tried?

Comment: What format do you want it in?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I basically just want to change the format to (D,M,Y) but I'm not sure how to do it in JQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the datepicker internal formatDate function.

Here's a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xdFr3/)

```
$('#dp').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yymmdd',
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: 60
});

$("#dp").change(function () {
    var tempDate = $('#dp').datepicker('getDate');
    var newformattedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', tempDate);
    $("#showDate").html(newformattedDate);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I display the new var inside .html()?

Comment: if the #showDate contains only the date, then you can just call the text() like this ,`$(#showDate).text()` after the conversion process

Comment: formatDate just outputs a string:  $('#showDate).html(newformattedDate);

Comment: @Geoff, yeah I tried that but it just kills datepicker. When the date is clicked the calendar stays visible & nothing happens

Comment: Basically what I want to do here is `var newformattedDate = $('#dp').val() THEN EDIT THE DATE FORMAT;`

Comment: Thanks @Geoff, that does work brilliantly and I will use it, although I did find another solution using the datepickers alt field and showing the value of that in #showDate.html() as well

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#dp").on("changeDate", function (ev) {
     var mydate= ev.date;// formate it as you like, as the the ev.date has date object
     alert("Day:"mydate.getDay() +"Month:"mydate.getMonth()+"Year:"mydate.getFullYear())
});
```